# how to do a misc device register inside probe of i2c_client driver.?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can somebody explain how to do misc device register(`misc_register`- virtual device) inside the i2c client driver's probe.

Comment: You call `misc_register`. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: yeah i did .. i wasn sure whether i can do it.. i did and it is working. thanks CL.